# GAM does not fit mean data well

Tags: r, time-series, gam

I am working on experimental data, where I applied different stressors over time (Day of experiment) to seastars. I measured the weight at different time points as well as their  righting time (activity). I used GAM to model the data over time. When plotting the model and the mean values for each time point, for the weight, the model is underestimating the actual measured mean weight.  And for the righting time the model shows a sinusoidal pattern, but the data don't support such pattern. It would be amazing if someone could explain to me why that is and if there is a possibility to fit the model better to my data. Thank you so much for your help.

My data look like this for weight:

```
Day.in.experiment  Treatment  Individual  Weight.sea.star..g.
numeric            factor     factor      numeric
```

And like this for the righting time:

```
Day.in.experiment  Treatment  Individual  Time..sec.
numeric            factor     factor      numeric
```

This is my code for the weight model:

```
model_weight <- bam (Weight.sea.star..g. ~ Treatment + 
                       s (Day.in.experiment, k = 3) +
                       s (Day.in.experiment, by = Treatment, k = 3) +
                       s (Individual, bs = "re"), 
                     family = gaussian, data = data_subset)

r1 <- start_value_rho (model_weight, plot = TRUE, lag = 2)

model_weight_autocorrelation <- bam (Weight.sea.star..g. ~ Treatment + 
                                   s (Day.in.experiment, k = 3) +
                                   s (Day.in.experiment, by = Treatment, k = 3) +
                                   s (Individual, bs = "re"), 
                                 family = gaussian, data = data_subset,
                                 rho = r1, AR.start = data_subset$start.event)
```

And this is the code for the activity model:

```
model_righting <- bam (Time..sec. ~ Treatment + 
                         s (Day.in.experiment, k = 7) +
                         s (Day.in.experiment, by = Treatment, k = 7) +
                         s (Individual, bs = "re") +
                         s (Individual, Day.in.experiment, bs = "re"), 
                       family = gaussian, data = data_subset)

r1 <- start_value_rho (model_righting, plot = TRUE, lag = 2)

model_righting_autocorrelation <- bam (Time..sec. ~ Treatment + 
                                         s (Day.in.experiment, k = 7) +
                                         s (Day.in.experiment, by = Treatment, k = 7) +
                                         s (Individual, bs = "re")+
                                         s (Individual, Day.in.experiment, bs = "re"),
                                       family = gaussian, data = data_subset,
                                       rho = r1, AR.start = data_subset$start.event)
```

In order to plot the model, I extracted the fitted data first and then plotted it with ggplot (). I provide the code for weight here, but I proceeded the very same way for righting time. To plot the mean values of the actual data I used another file called data_weight_mean.

```
data_model_weight_autocorrelation <- visreg (model_weight_autocorrelation, "Day.in.experiment", by = "Treatment",
                                             breaks = c ("NoHW", "THW", "TEHW"),
                                             gg = TRUE, overlay = TRUE, jitter = TRUE, lwd = 0.5,  
                                             rug = FALSE, partial = FALSE, plot = FALSE)

ggplot () +
  scale_fill_manual (breaks = c ("NoHW", "THW", "TEHW"),
                     values = c ("cadetblue3", "aquamarine3","goldenrod3"),
                     labels = c ("No Heatwave", "Ambient Heatwave", "Extended Heatwave")) +
  scale_color_manual (breaks = c ("NoHW", "THW", "TEHW"),
                      values = c ("cadetblue3", "aquamarine3","goldenrod3"),
                      labels = c ("No Heatwave", "Ambient Heatwave", "Extended Heatwave")) +
  geom_ribbon (data = data_model_weight_autocorrelation$fit, aes (x = Day.in.experiment,
                                                                  ymin = visregLwr, ymax = visregUpr, 
                                                                  fill = Treatment), alpha = 0.4, colour = "grey", size = 0.2) +
  geom_line (data = data_model_weight_autocorrelation$fit, aes (x = Day.in.experiment, y = visregFit, 
                                                                colour = Treatment),
             size = 1.1) +
  geom_point (data = data_weight_mean, aes (x = Day.in.experiment, y = Weight.sea.star..g., colour = Treatment),
              size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous (limits = c (-2, 12),
                      breaks = c (0, 4, 8, 12),
                      labels = c (0, 4, 8, 12)) +
  labs (x = "\nDay of Experiment", y = expression (atop ("Weight [g]")),
        colour = "Treatment", fill = "Treatment") +
  theme_bw () +
  theme (panel.grid.major.x = element_blank (),
         panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank (),
         panel.grid.major.y = element_blank (),
         panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank (),
         legend.position = c (0.15, 0.85),
         legend.direction = "vertical",
         legend.title = element_text (colour = "black", size = 18),
         legend.text = element_text (colour = "black", size = 16),
         axis.line = element_line (),
         axis.title = element_text (colour = "black", size = 24),
         axis.text = element_text (colour = "black", size = 18))
```

[image: Weight over experimental period]
[image: Righting time over experimental period]

Comment: How are you creating the plots? You need to show the code for that as there's a good chance that's where the problem lies given how widely used a tested *mgcv* is. Also, `gam` doesn't have a `rho` argument; did you mean to use `bam()`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the code for the plots. I hope that helps. I didn't realise gam doesn't have rho, so I changed my model to bam instead now, but the problems remain the same. Actually the plots did not change at all.